# Why [ ... ] syntax doesn't work in a Makefile while `test` does?

Tags: if-statement, makefile

I am on Linux Mint 19. I am entirely new to Makefiles.

Here is the problematic part:

```
[ $(shell id --user) -eq 0 ] && ( echo && echo "distrib target has to be run as normal user" && echo && exit 1 )
```

which throws this error:

```
[ 1000 -eq 0 ] && ( echo && echo "distrib target has to be run as normal user" && echo && exit 1 )
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'distrib' failed
make: *** [distrib] Error 1
```

---

On the contrary, using `test` command directly proves to be working entirely:

```
if test $(shell id --user) -eq 0; then ( echo && echo "distrib target has to be run as normal user" && echo && exit 1 ) fi
```

I want to ask why that is, did I break some Makefile rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with makefiles, it has to do with shell scripting and the difference between using `&&` vs. `if` in terms of the exit code.  You are comparing apples and oranges here.

It's not related to `test` vs `[`.  If you write the version using `[` inside an `if` statement you'll get the same behavior as you do with `test`, and if you write the `test` version with the `&&` model you'll get the same behavior as you do with `[`.

Run this in your shell:

```
[ 1000 -eq 0 ] && echo hi
echo $?
```

Now run this in your shell:

```
if [ 1000 -eq 0 ]; then echo hi; fi
echo $?
```

You'll see the former gives a non-0 exit code, while the latter gives a 0 (success) exit code.  That's how `if` works; it "swallows" the exit code of the condition.

Make always looks at the exit code of the shell script to decide if it failed or not.

Generally in make scripting you want to re-arrange your expressions to use `||` rather than `&&`.  That ensures that if the script exits early it exits with a success code not a failure code.  You can write your script like this:

```
[ $$(id -u) -ne 0 ] || ( echo && echo "distrib target has to be run as normal user" && echo && exit 1 )
```

Note I use `$$(id -u)` not `$(shell id --user)`; the recipe is run in the shell already and it's an anti-pattern to use the make `shell` function in a recipe.  Also, the `-u` option is a POSIX standard option while `--user` is only available in the GNU utilities version of `id`.